# How to interpret v.kernel network results

Tags: grass-gis, network, grass-7.0, density, kernel-density

v.kernel "Optionally generates a vector density map on a vector network."

I have done this for a network, but I don't understand how to interpret the output of this. Can anyone explain this? I am confused because the output map essentially just highlights every part of the network associated with a point. I have multiplied the results by the number of points (I read that I should do this), but the result doesn't give an informative picture of areas of high density...

[How to use GRASS v.kernel to calculate point densities along a network?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156803/how-to-use-grass-v-kernel-to-calculate-point-densities-along-a-network) I am essentially have a similar problem to this question that never got answered.